# Only BR HTML tag seems to work for GraphViz DOT labels

Tags: graphviz, dot

So here is my problem:

```
dot -Tpng <(echo  "digraph {x[label=<&sigma;<SUB>p</SUB>(x)>];}"  ) -o img.png
```

Creates this:

[image: \sigma_p(x)]

When it should have been putting `p` to a subscript

Also this

```
dot -Tpng <(echo  "digraph {x[label=<Hello<BR/>There>];}"  ) -o img.png
```

Works as expected:

[image: hello \ there]

```
$ dot -V                                                                                          
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
```

Comment: Works on http://viz-js.com/ using version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304), so maybe an command-line escape problem?

Comment: @marapet Doesn't work for me on viz-js.com, does work for me locally (2.38)

Comment: Sorry, seems to work only for svg - from the [documentation](http://graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html): The font markups for bold, italic, underlining, subscript and superscript [...] are currently only available via the cairo and svg renderers.